# Linux - Tor service won't start (ulimit -n)

Tags: tor

I'm running a web site on tor. For some reason the vps crashed and now every time I try to start the tor service it says this:

```
Stopping tor:                                              [FAILED]
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 32768.
Starting tor:                                              [  OK  ]
```

Even tho it says [ ok ] the service still isn't running.

I tried to Google this but it seems no one else is having this issue, what's wrong?

Thanks ^~^

Comment: What's in the logs? Which OS are you using? Maybe this question is better asked at http://tor.stackexchange.com

Comment: `Even tho it says [ ok ] the service still isn't running.` There's good news and there's bad news. The good news is that the service probably **is** running when it says `[ OK ]`, the bad news is that it probably crashes pretty quickly afterward. But there's more good news! It probably tells you why it crashed in the logs. Which you should check. I don't know where they'd be for Tor, but if the person who wrote the service is of sound mind the logs should be somewhere under `/var/log`.